# Is it possible to get the item index using Contains?

Tags: c#, collections

When I use `if (moscowCars.Contains(cars[x].Name))` it founds the value in a collection and I believe that not necessary to use `moscowCars.RemoveAt(moscowCars.FindIndex(o => o.Equals(cars[x].Name)));` to find it for a second time, just: `moscowCars.Remove(cars[x].Name);`. Of course, I can use `try & catch` instead of `if`, but I just want to know can I get the item index using `Contains`?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace Autoworld
    {
        class GoodCars
        {
            static List<Tech> cars = new List<Tech>();
            public class Tech
            {
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public double KM { get; set; }
            }
            static void Main()
            {
                List<string> moscowCars = new List<string>
                {
                    "GAZ-330811 Aper", "Lada Vesta Sport"
                };
                cars.Add(new Tech() { Name = "Lada Vesta Sport", KM = 190 });
                for (int x = 0; x < cars.Count; x++)
                {
                    if (moscowCars.Contains(cars[x].Name))
                    {
                        moscowCars.RemoveAt(moscowCars.FindIndex(o => o.Equals(cars[x].Name)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not use `IndexOf`?

Comment: you can use it like => `moscowCars.RemoveAt(moscowCars.IndexOf(cars[x].Name));`

Comment: Thanx, I will try!

Comment: @er-sho That's will throw an exception if the value isn't found because `IndexOf` will return -1.

Comment: @juharr, yes that right you need to first check if its return -1,

Comment: It works. I knew that is should be very simple, thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with just using `moscowCars.Remove(cars[x].Name)`? `.Remove` will just return false if the item is not found in the list

Comment: @SharpUser, you can also try as **devNull** said

Comment: @devNull, thank you, I will try.

Comment: Or `moscowCars.RemoveAll(x => x == cars[x].Name)` if you have duplicate values in the list and need to remove them all.

Comment: @juharr there is no duplicates, but anyway thank you. And I can't use `x => x` here, because it's already used with `for`. Can use `y => y` or some other letter. BTW, `moscowCars.RemoveAll(n => n.Equals(cars[x].Name));` works too.

Answer (score 2):

You could remove the two-step process entirely and just use [`.Remove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove?view=netframework-4.7.2) which will return:

> `true` if item is successfully removed; otherwise, `false`. This method
>   also returns `false` if itemwas not found in the List.

This would then look like:

```
for (int x = 0; x < cars.Count; x++) 
{ 
    moscowCars.Remove(cars[x].Name); 
}
```

And if you need to handle the case where no car is found to be removed, you can wrap that call in an `if` condition like:

```
for (int x = 0; x < cars.Count; x++) 
{ 
    if (!moscowCars.Remove(cars[x].Name))
    {
        // Handle no cars to remove
    }
}
```

Worth noting that behind the scenes, `.Remove` ultimately just gets the index and then removes the item at that index (which is what you were originally trying to do anyways):

```
public bool Remove(T item) {
    int index = IndexOf(item);
    if (index >= 0) {
        RemoveAt(index);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

See [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,db8cdd552a0bb10c,references) for the source.

---

Alternatively, as others have stated, if you expect the List to contain more than item to be removed, you can use [`.RemoveAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
moscowCars.RemoveAll(y => y == cars[x].Name);
```

And again, to handle the case where nothing is found:

```
if (moscowCars.RemoveAll(y => y == cars[x].Name) == 0)
{
    // Handle no cars to remove
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use IndexOf(item)
this will give you the index of the item, or -1 if 'item' was not found (making this method double as a "contains" as well)

Answer (score 0):

Use simply RemoveAt if you are sure you don't have any duplicated items anyway use the second way.

1. Solution

   ```
   static List<Tech> cars = new List<Tech>();
   public class Tech
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public double KM { get; set; }
   }

   static void Main()
   {
       List<string> moscowCars = new List<string>
           {
               "GAZ-330811 Aper", "Lada Vesta Sport"
           };

       cars.Add(new Tech() { Name = "Lada Vesta Sport", KM = 190 });

       for (int x = 0; x < cars.Count; x++)
       {
           if (moscowCars.Contains(cars[x].Name))
           {
               moscowCars.RemoveAt(moscowCars.IndexOf(cars[x].Name));
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Solution

   ```
   static List<Tech> cars = new List<Tech>();
   public class Tech
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public double KM { get; set; }
   }

   static void Main()
   {
       List<string> moscowCars = new List<string>
           {
               "GAZ-330811 Aper", "Lada Vesta Sport"
           };

       cars.Add(new Tech() { Name = "Lada Vesta Sport", KM = 190 });

       for (int x = 0; x < cars.Count; x++)
       {
           if (moscowCars.Contains(cars[x].Name))
           {
               moscowCars.RemoveAll(o => o == cars[x].Name);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

I hope it will help.

Comment: `moscowCars.RemoveAt(moscowCars.IndexOf(cars[x].Name));` - this is wthat I was searched for, thanks. Solution #2 searches twice as in my example, but founds all occurrences.